# How do you serialize a Node JS ChildProcess object?

Tags: node.js, serialization

I have a Node project that spawns several child processes using `fork()`.  When I fork a child process, I'm able to communicate with it with no problem using the child's `send()` method for passing messages.  However, I'm trying to expand the application to work as a cluster, which means no shared memory, so I'm adding Redis to be used as a shared data store.

I initially tried using JSON.serialize to store the ChildProcess object created by the `fork()` call, but that caused a circular JSON error.  So I tried using the `circular-json` package to serialize it; that worked, but when I parse (unserialize) it and try to use it to send a message, I get an error stating `TypeError: child[id].send is not a function`.  So then I tried the `node-serialize` package, but when I try to serialize a newly created ChildProcess object, I get an error stating `TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function`.

Is there a way to serialize and unserialize a Node ChildProcess object that preserves its methods/functions?

Comment: You can't.  A childProcess object is not entirely Javascript, it has native code behind it and thus can't be completely serialized and passed to a new process.  Even if you could, objects don't serialize with their methods, only data.

Comment: Can you provide more details on that, Patrick?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, you can send a native object, but don't serialize it, pass it via the [`sendHandle`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) parameter

Comment: @jfriend00 - is it possible to serialize a Node setTimeout or setInterval object?  (By the way, when you say "objects don't seraialize with their methods" - what about the `node-serialize` package?  It claims to serialize functions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-serialize)

Comment: I don't know of any way to serialize an actual `setTimeout()` object such that it could be used as the same object in another process. I'm not sure why you'd even try. If you want to communicate a specific time delay, just send the time delay as a number and on the other end, start a timer in your own environment with that time delay. You could make it "seem" like you were serializing the object by sending a tag indicating it was a timer object and sending a time remaining time and then upon deserialization, you create a timer object in your local environment set for that amount of time.

Comment: Serialization usually serializes data and perhaps some tags indicating what type of object was serialized.  It is rare to serialize code and when you say you serialized an object, one would assume you serialized the data in the object, not the code.  That doesn't mean one can't invent your own scheme for sending Javascript code if you want.  That could be made to work if the source was entirely trusted (because receiving code from an untrusted source is a disaster waiting to happen) and all the code was Javascript (no native code behind it).  It's usually not the efficient way to do things.

Comment: In your specific case the childProcess object has native OS handle behind it.  You can't serialize that strictly in Javascript.  If you just trying to send this object to another process on the same computer, some OSes allow you to transfer the raw OS handle betweeen processes.  The receiving process could then wrap a new childProcess object around that handle.

Comment: "I'm not sure why you'd even try." Normally, I wouldn't...but I'm trying to refactor existing code - code that starts and restarts forked children using setTimeout and setInterval calls. Sometimes, those need to be canceled/cleared. This works fine on a single process, but with multiple processes it won't work; I was hoping that I could just serialize the object, unserialize it in a different process, and then be able to call, for example, `clearInterval(my_interval)`. But if that won't work, I'll figure out a different way.

Comment: I was able to resolve my ChildProcess problem by using Redis' pub/sub functionality for message passing, instead of using Node's internal IPC functionality.